# Generic that could be object of type or reference of type

Tags: rust

Given a struct and trait:

```rust
// Minimal version of the actual data structure and trait
trait MyTrait {
    fn blub(&mut self);
}
struct MyStruct;
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn blub(&mut self) {
        println!("Blub!");
    }
}
```

I would like to create a struct that can hold an object that implements `MyTrait`:

```rust
impl<T> Foo<T>
where
    T: MyTrait,
{
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self { t }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        // Execute `blub` of `t`.
        // Something like:
        self.t.blub();
    }
}
```

So far, that's easy. Now comes the crux: I want to accept both owned and mutably referenced types, like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let t0 = MyStruct;
    let mut f0 = Foo::new(t0);
    f0.run();

    let mut t1 = MyStruct;
    let mut f1 = Foo::new(&mut t1);
    f1.run();
}
```

The code here of course doesn't work, because `&mut MyStruct` does not implement `MyTrait`.

In theory, this should be possible though, because `MyTrait::blub` takes `&mut self`, which is compatible with both owned and mutably borrowed types.

---

This is how far I've come. It works, but has two problems:

- It has a pointless second generic
- It requires `PhantomData`

```rust
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, marker::PhantomData};

// Minimal version of the actual data structure and trait
trait MyTrait {
    fn blub(&mut self);
}
struct MyStruct;
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn blub(&mut self) {
        println!("Blub!");
    }
}

// Object that shall carry objects OR mutable references of type `MyTrait`
struct Foo<T, U> {
    t: T,
    _p: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<T, U> Foo<T, U>
where
    T: BorrowMut<U>,
    U: MyTrait,
{
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self { t, _p: PhantomData }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        self.t.borrow_mut().blub();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t0 = MyStruct;
    let mut f0 = Foo::new(t0);
    f0.run();

    let mut t1 = MyStruct;
    let mut f1: Foo<_, MyStruct> = Foo::new(&mut t1);
    f1.run();
}
```

```
Blub!
Blub!
```

Is there a way to implement this more elegantly?

---

The only other elegant-ish way I have seen so far is to `impl MyTrait for &mut MyStruct`. Sadly, I do not own the trait or type, so I cannot do that. Although please tell me if my attempts here are misguided and this entire thing is an XY problem; and the actual thing I should do is to report this problem in said library so they can add that `impl`.

Comment: You can make `Foo::run` generic over `U: MyTrait` and constrain `T: BorrowMut<U>` (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4af5ebb33bac4532894665ab50d532b7)), however invoking it may require callers to explicitly specify `U` in order to disambiguate.

Comment: @eggyal Yah, it works, but it makes for a somewhat awkward API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to add another implantation of `MyTrait` for `&mut MyStruct`.

```
impl MyTrait for &mut MyStruct {
    fn blub(&mut self) {
        println!("Blub!");
    }
}
```

---

If you dont have access to the struct or trait, you can use an `enum` to manage the Owned and Borrowed versions and implement `Deref`/`DerefMut` to keep the usage of `t` the same.

```
enum Container<'a, T> {
    Owned(T),
    Borrowed(&'a mut T)
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> From<T> for Container<'a, T> {
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Self::Owned(t)
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> From<&'a mut T> for Container<'a, T> {
    fn from(t: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        Self::Borrowed(t)
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Deref for Container<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Owned(o) => o,
            Self::Borrowed(o) => o
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> DerefMut for Container<'a, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        match self {
            Self::Owned(o) => o,
            Self::Borrowed(o) => o
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    t: Container<'a, T>
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T>
where
    T: MyTrait,
{
    fn new(t: impl Into<Container<'a, T>>) -> Self {
        Self{ t: t.into() }
    }

    fn run(&mut self) {
        self.t.blub();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Finomnis I have updated my answer with an alternative.

Comment: Cool idea, the enum :) that might work.

Comment: Why does it allow you to both `impl<'a, T> From<T> for Container<'a, T>` and `impl<'a, T> From<&'a mut T> for Container<'a, T>` simultaneously? Couldn't `T` in the first one also be a `&mut`? Or is the fact that the first `T` doesn't carry a lifetime enough for the compiler to understand that those can never trigger both?

Comment: @Finomnis It could be, but If the generic in the first one was `&mut T`, then the second one would be `&mut &mut T`.

Comment: It doesn't, actually, without explicit type annotations: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8a1a07973d3e2fd6489efc0cf90bff1 But I wonder if it's possible at all without explicit annotations.

Comment: @Finomnis because you want different return types depending on the `T` passed in to `new`, it makes sense why the return value is somewhat ambiguous for rust's current type resolver, hence type annotations. I imagine you probably could get it working without type annotations with some intermediate trait with an associated type but im not sure its worth the complexity.

Comment: I tried, based on your idea and an intermediate trade, but then I get the expected 'conflicting implementations' error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=59f3f6f9137487efb8eedaf8088c6bc5

Comment: Actually, your first idea **does** work! It just needed some extra trait annotations in `From` to make it unambiguous: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15ebf5d3f9828404ad297893421313a0

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions I found:

This one doesn't require looking at an enum at runtime, it solves types at compile time:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

// Minimal version of the actual data structure and trait
trait MyTrait {
    fn blub(&mut self);
}

struct MyStruct;
impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn blub(&mut self) {
        println!("Blub!");
    }
}

trait MyTraitFrom<'a, T> {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self;
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, T> for &'a mut T {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut T) -> Self {
        value
    }
}

impl<'a, T: MyTrait> MyTraitFrom<'a, &'a mut T> for &'a mut T {
    fn mytrait_from(value: &'a mut &'a mut T) -> Self {
        let value: &'a mut T = value;
        value
    }
}

struct Foo<T, U> {
    t: T,
    _p: PhantomData<U>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a, U: 'a> Foo<T, U>
where
    &'a mut U: MyTraitFrom<'a, T>,
    U: MyTrait,
{
    fn new(t: T) -> Self {
        Self { t, _p: PhantomData }
    }

    fn run(&'a mut self) {
        let u: &'a mut U = MyTraitFrom::mytrait_from(&mut self.t);
        u.blub();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t0 = MyStruct;
    let mut f0 = Foo::new(t0);
    f0.run();

    let mut t1 = MyStruct;
    let mut f1 = Foo::new(&mut t1);
    f1.run();
}
```

```
Blub!
Blub!
```